# How do I retrieve the data between "_id=" and "&"?

Tags: regex

How do I parse string "7c23a12f0cffa6cf2fac0baf8eacf4c1" from a file ..  I am trying to retrieve the data between `_id=` and `&`

example file:

```
4593733f4ab534f0001ecbe20000b3e9/cgi-bin/rsspipes/dispatch?Alternative=10&Category=ECMINSTITUTE&Type=News&_action=run&_id=7c23a12f0cffa6cf2fac0baf8eacf4c1&_out=json&_render=json&_time=&dojo_preventCache=1253389550099Z1f8wengine.pipes.yahoo.com:8080rhttp://ecminstitute.appspot.com/gMozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_4_11; en) AppleWebKit/531.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.3 Safari/531.910jdmm6t5aneif&b=4&d=zhJNm4hpYEL50eT2b_Zabr3mZKV2C34ShzuA1A--&s=qm&i=.a0EUfWk9n2pue72QqA3
```

Answer (score 4):

```
id=([^&]*)&
```

The data between id= and & will be matched by the first (and only) group and then be accessible via `.group(1)` or similar depending on the language/regex library.

Edit: Changed `+` to `*` as per Johannes Rössel's suggestion.

Comment: Make the `+` a `*` to avoid strange results when id is empty under some weird circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

Use a regex like this one:

```
_id=([a-f0-9]+)&
```

The parenthesis define a group which you can retrieve from the results.

Answer (score 3):

This is a little more robust than some of the alternatives.

```
[&?]_id=([a-f0-9]+)(?:[&]|$)
```

```
[&?] # makes sure it isn't part of another parameter
_id=
(
  [a-f0-9]+ # at least one hexadecimal digit
)
(?:
  [&] # make sure there isn't some trailing data
|
  $   # might be at the end of the string
)
```

Comment: good catch - the end-of-string would break everyone else's regexps. i'd still recommend using a cgi param parsing utility, since there's a good chance your language ships one with the stdlib and it'll have taken care of the edge cases.

Comment: +1. YOu have just convinced me that I need to practice my regexps. I would not have covered all your cases if I had written a similar regexp today.

Comment: If you need it to return "empty but true" for cases where `_id` is set to nothing " `&_id=&` " replace `[a-f0-9]+` with `[a-f0-9]*`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use

```
perl -ne 'm/[&?]_id=([^&]+)(&|$)/ && print $1;' [file]
```

where `[file]` is the name of the file containing the data.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the following (non-greedy) Perl regex:

```
/_id=(.*?)&/
```

Comment: `/_id=([^&]+)/` would be faster.

Comment: Could you please explain why that is the case? Is it because of the greedy vs non-greedy matching?